# Adding custom x-axis categories to c# programmatically created excel line chart

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I can't work out how to programmatically add custom categories to an excel line chart created in  C#.

Most of the examples I have found do this by selecting the source data from an existing excel worksheet(e.g. with something like `chart.DataRange = sheet.Range["A1:E5"];`).

However my source data does not come from an existing sheet and I don't really want to have to create a new sheet, write my data to it and then use this as the source.

This is the method I have at the moment for creating the chart:

```
public void PlotLineChart(Excel.Worksheet ws, List<double[]> seriesData, String[] xAxisCategories, String[] seriesNames, String chartTitle, String yAxisTitle, String xAxisTitle) { 
            Excel.ChartObjects charts    = (Excel.ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            ChartObject        chart     = (ChartObject)charts.Add(10, 80*(plotCount + 1), 1000 ,800);
            Excel.Chart        chartPage = chart.Chart;
            chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers;
            chartPage.HasTitle = true;
            chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = chartTitle;
                
            var yAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
            yAxis.HasTitle = true;
            yAxis.AxisTitle.Text = yAxisTitle;

            var xAxis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory);
            xAxis.HasTitle      = true;
            xAxis.AxisTitle.Text = xAxisTitle;
       //     xAxis.CategoryNames = categories;

            Excel.SeriesCollection col = (SeriesCollection)chartPage.SeriesCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < seriesData.Count; i++) {
                Excel.Series ser = col.NewSeries();
                ser.Name   = seriesNames[i];
                ser.Values = seriesData[i];
                ser.XValues = xAxisCategories;            }
            
        }
```

This plots the chart more-or-less as I want it, but the x-axis is just arbitrarily numbered rather than having the category names (specified by the xAxisCategories argument to the method).

As you can see, I've tried adding the categories both by adding them to the individual data series, and by adding them to the x-axis itself however neither of these seem to work.

I'm using Microsoft Office Developer Tools in Visual Studio (2019).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Lee